# Django AssertionError No api proxy found for service "memcache"

Tags: django, google-app-engine, memcached

I'm running a Django app on GAE and I want to use memcache in my `views.py` to store some data for caching. I have not setup anything for caching in my `settings.py` and immediately use `from google.appengine.api import memcache` inside of `views.py` and pulls/insert data using the `.add()` and `.get()` method. This however, results in an

```
AssertionError at / : No api proxy found for service "memcache"
```

What am i missing here? Should I be setting up something inside of `settings.py`? From my understanding memcache is a built-in feature of GAE and I figured it worked the same way as an API key where we would not need to specify them inside of the `settings.py`

Plus the documentation also does not provide any information on proxy setup or whatsoever.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @NoCommandLine python3.9

Comment: Python 3 does not have the bundled services enabled by default. Did you follow the guidelines (steps) documented on this page - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/access#django

Comment: @NoCommandLine Oh I see thank you so much. However, after following the docs you have given above, in step 2 it states to `Add the following code in your main Python script`, do you know in which Django file should I be adding this to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving details from comments section to full answer

1. Python 3 does not have the bundled services enabled by default. You have to follow the guidelines documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/access#django) to enable them.
2. Regarding question by OP (in comments section) - your Django App will have a 'main' file that is launched when you invoke your app i.e. the file that has the `app` object or where you import the `application` module(a common name for this file is `main.py`). It is in that file that you add the code because it will serve as a wrapper to the `application` module